# VBA IE How to click a button with MouseEvetns 'mouseover' and 'mouseleave'

Tags: html, excel, vba, automation, webautomation

I am having challenges automating a website with elements that requires a `click` action. Example of those elements are search icons, link and buttons. One thing similar to these elements when I inspect them is that they have an EventListener 'mouseenter' and 'mouseover' and also I noticed that they have an attribute `hidefocus="on"` and `unselectable="on"` which I thinking a property that block me on controlling these elements. Below is a sample source code which is for the button Login, the main element is `<a>` and the events are attached to it and there is a children `<span>` element with no event listener.

```html
<a tabindex="0" class="x-btn-default-small" id="button-1028" role="button" aria-disabled="false" aria-hidden="false" hidefocus="on" unselectable="on" data-componentid="button-2018" data-qtip="Login">

<span class="x-btn-icon" id="button-1028-btnIconEl" role="presentation" data-ref="btnIconEl" unselectable="on" qa="btnIcon-loginButton">Login<span>
```

The `id` of this button is dynamically changing so I cannot rely on that attribute, so I am using the `innerText` property instead. Below are the codes I already tried that did not work.

```vb
Dim hrf As HTMLAnchorElement

'1st
For Each hrf In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If hrf.innerText = "Login" Then
        hrf.Click: Exit For
    End If
Next hrf

'2nd
For Each hrf In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If hrf.innerText = "Login" Then
        hrf.FireEvent "onmouseover"
        hrf.FireEvent "onmousedown"
        hrf.FireEvent "onmouseup"
        Exit For
    End If
Next hrf

'3rd
For Each hrf In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If hrf.innerText = "Login" Then
        hrf.FireEvent "onclick"
        hrf.FireEvent "onmouseenter"
        hrf.FireEvent "onmouseleave"
        Exit For
    End If
Next hrf

'4th - dispatch event
Set evt = ie.document.createEvent("HTMLEvents") 'also tried "MouseEvents"
evt.initEvent "onclick", True, True 'also tried "onmouseenter", "mouseenter", "click", true, false/ false, false/false, true
For Each hrf In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If hrf.innerText = "Login" Then
        hrf.dispatchEvent evt
        Exit For
    End If
Next hrf
```

I also tried using the span element but still it's not working. Hope you can help me.

Comment: Is your `If hrf.innerText = "Login"` ever true? Is it `"Login"` as opposed to e.g. `"   Login"`?

Comment: Is the index of the anchor element known and constant? Have you tried reaching it using `ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")(index)`, where `index=0,1...,n`?

Comment: yes I also tried that, and yes the code was able to find the element using the innertext

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `data-qtip` attribute and its value? Obviously use this as basis for `.FireEvent` or `.dispatchEvent` as required. No looping required.

```
ie.document.querySelector("[data-qtip=Login]").click
```